Is there a comprehensive list of Win32 functions that indicate error with `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`?
The Win32 CreateFile function is well-known for returning INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE rather than NULL in the case of failure. This has apparently been a source of confusion for programmers.
Is there a comprehensive list of Win32 API functions that return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE instead of NULL to indicate failure? (Functions like GetCurrentProcess, which can return a pseudo-handle whose value happens to equal INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE which doesn't indicate failure, are not counted.)

There is no such list provided by Microsoft, and I doubt any such 3rd party list exist, either. All we can do is look at the documentation for individual API functions to know what they return and why.

even if there was such a list - what would be the use of it? anyway, each API call needs to be coded separately. remember or look at its parameters, return value, error codes, etc. instead of looking at the list - look at the documentation for each specific API, if we don't remember without it

There is no list of Win32 functions that indicate error with INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.
I suggest you could refer to the blog: Why are HANDLE return values so inconsistent?
